# How to make editable text when creating text to points in p5 js?

Tags: text, dynamic, p5.js

i am new to p5 and i am experimenting with the function textToPoints.
I am trying to find how i can make the text given to be converted to points, dynamic to the user. I found the createP and createInpute functions but i can't understand how and if its possible to connect them somehow.

Thanks in advance

```
    let font;
 function preload() {
  font = loadFont("brangus.otf");
 }
let points;
let size=100;
let hiArray;

let str = '';
let inp

function setup() {
  var myCanvas =createCanvas(400, 400);

  inp = createInput('');
  inp.position(200, 200);
  inp.size(400);
  inp.input(inputChange);
  

 textFont(font);
 textSize(size);
  noStroke();
  
      fill(255, 104, 204);
  

 }


function inputChange() {  
  hiArray = font.textToPoints (inp.value(),60,200,size);
  console.log(inp.value());
   
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  
 for (let i=0; i<hiArray.length; i++) {
ellipse (hiArray[i].x, hiArray[i].y,10,10);
  }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this doesn't work for you just present your code so I can help you.

```
let str = '';
let inp
function setup() {
  createCanvas(500,500);
  background(255);
  
  
  inp = createInput('');
  inp.position(0, 0);
  inp.size(100);
  inp.input(inputChange);
}

function inputChange() {  
  console.log(inp.value()); //here you can fit the textToPoints function, where the inp.value() is the text you are changing
//this only runs when the input text is changed, so if you're actively changing the points in some way then just fit that in the draw function and change the array in here.
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I embedded the code on the post.